# How can I find the generating idempotent $e(x)$ from generating polynomial $g(x) $

Tags: coding-theory

In the book "Fundamentals of Error-Correcting Codes" this was written

One way to find the generating idempotent $e(x)$ for a cyclic code
$C$ from the generator polynomial $g(x)$ is to solve $1 = a(x)g(x) + b(x)h(x)$ for $a(x)$ using the Euclidean Algorithm, where $h(x) = (x^n − 1)/g(x)$. Then reducing $a(x)g(x)$ modulo $x^n − 1$ produces $e(x)$.
could any one help me 
How this

For example I cant verify this when i try to solve :
Exercise 218 : Verify the entries in the table in Example 4.3.4. page(133)
[the book](https://books.google.ps/books?id=RAsjychHkLYC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=find%20the%20generating%20idempotent%20e(x)%20for%20a%20cyclic%20code%20C%20from%20the%20generator%20polynomial%20g(x)&source=bl&ots=GwEyUvwe1k&sig=-MeQmX18w8STPF9zN0vWFEPDp-I&hl=ar&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=find%20the%20generating%20idempotent%20e(x)%20for%20a%20cyclic%20code%20C%20from%20the%20generator%20polynomial%20g(x)&f=false) thanks

Comment: What exactly don't you get about the proof given in the book?

Comment: I can not find the generating  idempotent  for a cyclic code from the generator polynomial .

Comment: They define $e(x)$ to be the polynomial such that $e(x) \equiv a(x)g(x) \mod x^n -1$ and show that it satisfies $e(x)^2 = e(x)$, proving that it is idempotent.

Comment: But how I can get $a(x)$ ?.

Comment: Do you know Euclidean division?

Comment: yes , you mean I should divide $g(x)$ by $h(x)$  using Euclidean division or what ?

Comment: and do you know the lemma of Bezout Bachet? It states that $\text{gcd}(g(x), h(x)) = a(x)g(x) + b(x)h(x)$ for some $a(x), b(x)$.

Comment: If you know this, then since we have that $\text{gcd}(g(x), h(x)) = 1$, then there are $a(x), b(x)$ such that $1 = a(x)g(x) + b(x)h(x)$. The proof of the lemma of Bezout Bachet follows from using the Euclidean division algorithm which gives you the gcd and then you work back from this gcd to find these $a(x), b(x)$.

Comment: You just have to use the extended Euclidean algorithm between $g$ and $h$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They define $e(x)$ to be the polynomial such that $e(x)≡a(x)g(x)$mod $x^n−1$ and show that it satisfies $e(x)2=e(x)$, proving that it is idempotent.